# Хаха, да я щупаю верх кармана!

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы

Так можно сказать или правильно только *"ощупываю"?*

Comment: А что это — верх кармана?

Comment: Верхняя часть его, где-то на уровне той штуки, которая его сверху застёгивает.

Comment: Верхняя часть на уровне штуки такой. Ну хорошо. А что такое — верх кармана?

Comment: Да что Вы прицепились?! Я разве не объяснил только что? Что Вы то же самое спрашиваете, когда я уже ответил?

Comment: Очень мило. Остыньте, и тогда поймёте, что не ответили, хотя отреагировали. Отвечать, впрочем, никто не обязывает.

Comment: *Остыньте...* Да я совершенно спокоен. *...поймёте, что не ответили...* — по-моему, я ответил, а если Вы чего-то не поняли, можете именно это и уточнить. И что Вы милого нашли, совсем непонятно.)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так сказать можно, поскольку слово "щупаю" охватывает более конкретные смыслы, выражаемые его модификациями:

- ощупываю (выясняю на ощупь свойства имеющегося под рукой предмета: на этой ли (надетой) рубашке карман с кредиткой),
- нащупываю (нахожу на ощупь застёжку) или пытаюсь нащупать (о менее результативном действии),
- прощупываю (область поиска на ощупь),
- пощупываю (время от времени проверяю на ощупь, на месте ли пачка долларов; возможно, получаю удовольствие от сознания того, что недавно нашёл столько денег).

Если вы искали что-то в верхней части кармана, возможно, точнее "ощупываю" (карман под рукой есть, выясняется содержимое верхней части) или "прощупываю" (эта часть кармана - зона поиска).

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Вы всё расставили по своим местам: "щупаю" включает все смыслы, но подобрать более узкий вариант может быть лучше в конкретном случае.

Answer (score 1):

Да нет, не думаю, что есть запрет *щупать* что-либо. Почему бы и не верх кармана?! Возможно, правда, тут есть оттенки смысла, но не настолько же, чтобы слово не употреблять?!

А в чем сомнение? В самом слове или в сочетании с карманом?

Comment: Сомнение в том, что в этом контексте слово "щупать" годится. Это я сам с собой так сказал, когда искал ключ в кармане и уж было решил, что не взял его. Оказалось, что я искал в верхней его части и не заметил, что он и дальше вниз продолжается. После этого оказалось, что ключ на месте.)) Вот я и задумался, а правильно я сказал "щупаю". Просто мне показалось, что "щупаю" может прозвучать как просто "трогаю", поэтому звучит не совсем точно, а "ощупываю" будет примерно как *осматриваю во всех местах, "прохожусь" рукой, пытаясь найти.* Показалось, что если сказать "щупаю", могут не понять зачем.

Comment: *Просто мне показалось, что "щупаю" может прозвучать как просто "трогаю",* - нет, не думаю. На мой взгляд, если разница в значениях "щупать" и "ощупывать" и есть, то точно не в этом. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%89%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x Хотя согласен, иногда хочется сказать именно "ощупывать", но это, видимо, фонетические предпочтения, совсем не семантические и/или грамматические.

Comment: Ну хорошо, значит, я правильно сказал сразу, спасибо.